# Implement Websocket Plugin for Vuex 4 under Vue 3 (socket library agnostic)

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a Vue 3 application working with Vuex 4 and what I'm trying to do is centralize all my websocket operations via Vuex. I'm Following [this tutorial](http://iamnotmyself.com/2020/02/14/implementing-websocket-plugins-for-vuex/) but I'm not being able to wire up my plugin to the Vuex store. Ref websockets I need to be as agnostic as possible so can't use any libraries or socket.io:

Here's my plugin code:

```
var store = null
var ws = null

function startWebsocket() {
    ws = new WebSocket('socketURL')
    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log('webSocket: on message: ', event.data)
        const wsData = JSON.parse(event.data)
        store.dispatch('websocket/processRemoteMessage', wsData)
    }
    ws.onopen = function (event) {
        console.log('webSocket: on open: ', event)
        store.dispatch('connectionOpened')
    }
    ws.onclose = function (event) {
        console.log('webSocket: on close: ', event)
        store.dispatch('connectionClosed')
        ws = null
        setTimeout(startWebsocket, 5000)
    }
    ws.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log('webSocket: on error: ', event)
    }
}

export default function createWebSocketPlugin() {
    return (store_param) => {
        store = store_param;
        startWebsocket();
    }
}
```

As you can see when the websocket brings a new message I parse the object and then I want to be able to dispatch an action from the websocket store (this module lives outside the plugin) passing the websocket message:

```
store.dispatch('websocket/processRemoteMessage', wsData)
```

This is my websocket Vuex module:

```
export const namespaced = true
export const state = {
    connected: false,
    error: null,
    connectionId: '',
    statusCode: '',
    incomingChatInfo: [],
    remoteMessage: [],
    messageType: '',
}
export const actions = {
    processRemoteMessage({ commit }, wsData) {
        commit('SET_REMOTE_DATA', wsData)
    },
    connectionOpened({ commit }) {
        commit('SET_CONNECTION', true)
    },
    connectionClosed({ commit }) {
        commit('SET_CONNECTION', false)
    },
    connectionError({ commit }, error) {
        commit('SET_ERROR', error)
    },
}
export const mutations = {
    SET_REMOTE_DATA(state, wsData) {
        state.messageType = wsData.type
        state.connectionId = wsData.connectionId
        state.incomingChatInfo = wsData.documents
    },
    SET_CONNECTION(state, message) {
        state.connected = message
    },
    SET_ERROR(state, error) {
        state.error = error
    },
}
```

And this is my store index where I import all the vuex modules and the plugin:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import * as chatQueue from '@/store/modules/chatQueue'
import * as messages from '@/store/modules/messages'
import * as notification from '@/store/modules/notification'
import * as shifts from '@/store/modules/shifts'
import * as tickets from '@/store/modules/tickets'
import * as token from '@/store/modules/token'
import * as user from '@/store/modules/user'
import * as websocket from '@/store/modules/websocket'
import * as createWebSocketPlugin from '@/store/plugins/createWebSocketPlugin'

export default createStore({
    modules: {
        chatQueue,
        messages,
        notification,
        shifts,
        tickets,
        user,
        token,
        websocket,
    },
    plugins: [createWebSocketPlugin],
    strict: false,
})
```

When I try to run the APP I inmediatly get this error:

```
vuex.esm-bundler.js:935 Uncaught TypeError: plugin is not a function
at vuex.esm-bundler.js:935:46
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at new Store2 (vuex.esm-bundler.js:935:11)
at createStore (vuex.esm-bundler.js:880:10)
at index.js?t=1644319834874:12:16
```

I'm a total newbie when it comes to Vuex Plugins and websockets so pretty sure I'm messing something up when I try either to import or wire up my plugin to my Vuex store.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because of the `createWebSocketPlugin()` method declaration?

The framework might be expecting a `socket` parameter for `createWebSocketPlugin(socket)` in order to provide a socket object for you automatically. In the documentation, this method is presented with a `socket` parameter. Moreover, judging by the error message `at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)`, Vuex.esm-bundler might be looping through the arguments array in order to provide a socket object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should import it like:

```js
import createWebSocketPlugin from '@/store/plugins/createWebSocketPlugin'
```

because you are basically saying import all "exports" into `createWebSocketPlugin.`
Run a `console.log` on `createWebSocketPlugin` and I suspect that the createWebSocketPlugin will show you a Module instance instead of the function of the `export default`